# installing dtrace on ubuntu with latest kernel

Tags: kernel, debugging, tools

I am on

## uname -a

Linux ubuntu 4.11.0-rc3+ #5 SMP Tue Apr 4 12:05:39 PDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

When I typed 'dtrace', it asked me to install systemtap. Now I have:
systemtap-sdt-dev/yakkety,now 3.0-7 amd64 [installed]

In FreeBSD, there is 'dtrace -l' to see all static probes which you can trace. How do I see those here in ubuntu? what am I missing? I am trying to find a good doc that can explain such things to me.
Thanks in advance.